# Server CPU overloads after trying to Insert Image in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

Basically I am trying to insert an image to the Homepage, and once I do so, server CPU raise and often causes error 500 or 501, and server restarts.

To insert an image I go to CMS--> Home Page--> Content--> Insert Image--> Click on the Folder in **Storage Root** called: Background.

There are 50 images in Background folder, and trumbnails take 1 minute to load, but while they are loading, server CPU raises and server restarts. This has starter only recently.

What is causing it ?

Comment: error log? strace?

Comment: error log shows that sever was overloaded.. Checked slow queries but they are unrelated to this event.. I mean there were no slow queries during server crash. I am a bit lost to be honest, when using Internet Explorer the server overloads but all thumbnails load, however when using firefox or Chrome browser the server load rises very high, thumbnails dont load, and server crashes... I just dont understand how  Explorer browser doesn't cause server to crash, its just very very strange.

Comment: Resize the images locally before uploading to <2000 pixels and try again. Magento normally doesn't resize onsave but onrequest. So maybe a third party module disturbing things